# human agency -> physical force, à la 'mystification'?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I seek a word that appropriately denigrates the tendency to obscure accountable human agents as unaccountable natural or physical ones. What I mean:

English has a useful pejorative='mystification' for the process by which natural phenomena are portrayed as supernatural. This ancient tendency continues today in, e.g., the ascription of the origin and development of biological species and traits to "intelligent design" rather than evolution.

A [recent CBC piece](http://www.cbc.ca/radio/ideas/it-s-the-economists-stupid-1.3219471) makes the case that many (probably most) contemporary Anglosphere economists have abandoned empiricality to serve wealth and power. One way this is done in discourse (esp in US corporate-funded economics media) is to portray "the markets" as like a physical force, rather than as being the aggregate of a small number of humans whose extreme wealth gives them financial market power. But I can't think of a pithy, one-word pejorative (à la 'mystification') for the generic process by which social processes (conducted by morally-accountable agents) are obscured by recasting them as physical (hence unaccountable) ones. Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Bjr, Rather an astute question.  I often use "animism" in such discussions; (environmentalism for example is just the latest upswelling of peurile animism, with a few risible terms someone saw in a scientific journal added for effect).  I realise it's not precisely what you're asking, but in the arena

Comment: really the more I thought on it, "anthropomorphising" is probably what you're after here, Tom.  If not, it would anyway be exactly in your arsenal for your field of enquiry.

Comment: @Joe Blow: what I'm describing STM to be the *opposite* of anthropomorphising, no? ISTM folks who use the term "anthropomorphization" tend to be denigrating the ascription of human-like agency (or at least cognition) to entities (typically animals other than humans) that the user of the term considers to be unworthy of the ascription. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you refering to [behavioral economics](http://nowandfutures.com/d2/BehavioralEconomics%28conventional%29ribe239.pdf) ? Other link: [Is Behavioral Economics Doomed? The ordinary versus the extraordinary](http://www.dklevine.com/papers/behavioral-doomed.pdf)

Comment: Hi Tom just a production note, as I understand the site as a new user you should basically "thumb up" all the answers, so as to give yourself points to you can edit and stuff.  Anthropomorphise ...so, I'll edit some more in to my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a pre-existing term that captures this exactly, but I might go with something like:

- *fatilization*
- *naturalization*
- *physicalization*

Comment: `physicalization` does seem to be close to what I want ... just not quite pithy enough. So I'll wait a bit for something sexier (and preferably already in use--I'd say, "not a virgin word" except I don't want this comment to get too inappropriate :-) to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term could also apply to those who alienate otherwise sympathetic  people by insisting on bashing essentially unrelated beliefs, e.g. religion.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're looking for anthropomorphizing.

You're argument or position is quite subtle, but I have often said things like, "naive idiots anthropomorphise the markets..."

Anthropomorphise ... so, as you say, naive people (well, in your opinion and mine they are naive) .. naive people *"portray 'the markets' as like a physical force"* ...

Regarding your further comments, what I would say is, when I am discussing (and I often do) absolutely precisely the phenomenon you describe (so: personifying 'the markets', seeing 'the markets' as an entity which acts, embodying 'the markets' as an entity rather like a god, a person, or a 'gaia'-like conscious force) ... when I discuss precisely that phenomenon, I use "anthropomorphise" commonly.  So, I have often literally said to a trader "You're anthropomorphising the [oil, whatever] market."

---

(By the way, as a detail, nobody knows if it's an "s" or "z" near the end there.)

On a philosophical note, I agree that *"the Enlightenment has, and how, ended"*: we live in a macroshitorical era of tokenism, of belief in fairies; animism is one of the main (perhaps overriding) base philosophies of the day; and the hyper-religious sentiment of the day (complete with inquisitions, crusades, etc) is overwhelming.  As I say, the very precise word you're looking for may not be "anthropomorphising" but it (and *animism*) is in there at your service; maybe it's the SWR you were after?